How to set custom dialog full screen? (android)
I want to show custom dialog in full screen.
But It's not now.
I don't know why.
This is my code
val dialog = Dialog(requireContext())
val view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.custom, null)

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
dialog.setContentView(view)
dialog.window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
dialog.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
dialog.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
dialog.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY



Replace
val dialog = Dialog(requireContext()) 

with
val dialog = Dialog(requireContext(), 
android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)


Thank you for your answer. great help to me
